Prediction values don't match fitted function from GAM model
I have a presence/absence data for a species occurrence and I did a binomial GAM using sea surface temperature (sst) as a predictor variable.
My df object is a data.frame with the presence/absence data for the species (0/1), the date and the coordinates of each point (WGS84) and the corresponding sst extracted from satellite observations.
gam<-mgcv::gam(sfr_presence ~ s(sst), family=binomial, 
    data=df, method="REML")

Family: binomial 
Link function: logit 

Formula:
sfr_presence ~ s(sst)

Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -3.17801    0.05595   -56.8   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
         edf Ref.df Chi.sq p-value    
s(sst) 5.853  6.862    553  <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.0385   Deviance explained = 9.54%
-REML = 5886.8  Scale est. = 1         n = 25297

plot(gam,trans=plogis)


I'm trying to predict the probability of occurrence of this species for a new dataset, but the values that result from the predict function are very low compared with the scale of the fitted function of sst from the gam.
The new dataset includes sst data from the same source and for the same area considered for model fitting.
pred<-mgcv::predict.gam(gam,se.fit=T,newdata=df_test, 
        type="response", backtransform=TRUE)

summary(pred$fit)

Min.    1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
0.02190 0.09596 0.11609 0.10250 0.11829 0.12178      21

summary(df_test$sst)
Min.   1st Qu.  Median   Mean   3rd Qu.  Max.    NA's 
19.60   21.24   21.95   21.99   22.72   24.43      21 

If the average of sst in the new dataset is around 22ºC shouldn't the average prediction be around 0.7?

Your plot only depicts the (centered) smooth. You need to consider the intercept. Use the ‘shift’ argument of plot.gam.

(1) It's hard to say for sure without  a reproducible example. Jensen's inequality could be partly responsible, but it looks like the response surface is approximately linear over most of the range of your predictors, so ...  (2) is backtransform=TRUE actually doing anything? I think type="response" should do everything you need, and backtransform is most likely getting silently ignored ...

Thank you very much for the help, adding the intersept made the difference in the interpretation of the plots.

Q1
plot(gam, trans=plogis)

this only transforms the smooth from the link scale to the response scale. As the model has an intercept, you would need to add it's value first, then transform. See the shift argument, but it would just be easier to predict()...
Q2
There is no argument backtransform to predict.gam and as Ben Bolker surmised, it is just being silently ignored. As you already asked for type = "response", you are getting response-scale predicted values anyway. The standard error on this cale is not very useful however; if you want to create a credible interval you should do it on the link scale and then back transform. My package gratia has fitted_values() which will do this for you.
